# Shapiro-Wilk normality test for multiple variables in R

Tags: r, variables

Shapiro-Wilk normality test for multiple variables in R: I have a dataset called data, and three continuous variables called a, b, c. How can I write a for loop to do shapiro.test() for the variables respectively?

Comment: See `apply` in base R for instance.

Comment: thank you. I finally make it. vars <- c("a","b","c"); lshap<- lapply(data[,vars],shapiro.test);
lshap;
lshaps <- sapply(lshap,`[`,c("statistic", "p.value"));
lshaps;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If you have 3 vectors a, b, c:

```
    vars <- list(a, b, c)
    result <- list()
    for(i in seq(length(vars))) {
        result <- append(result, shapiro.test(vars[[i]]))
    }
```

> If you have a dataframe:

```
    result <- list()
    for(i in seq(dim(data)[2])) {
        result <- append(result, shapiro.test(data[[i]]))
    }
```

Comment: But how to specify the dataset?

Comment: what is the class of your dataset?

Comment: the class is data frame

Answer (score 1):

contributed by a friend.

```
for (i in 1:3){print(shapiro.test(data[,i]))}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just so you are aware, it is generally a bad practice to loop through independent hypothesis tests in this way. Each time you do so, you are embracing a small amount of risk (Typically 5%, if alpha is 0.05), then if you had 100 variables, you would literally be accepting an aggregate risk of `0.05+0.05+0.05+...+0.05 = 0.05*100`. This is unreasonable.Even if they all passed the test of normality, you are now certain (probabilistic-ally) that together there exists no confidence that they all hold true. It is not strictly additive as mentioned above, but is close. Each variable you are `0.95` confident in your conclusion, then by the second time it becomes `0.95^2`, and so it goes on. This leaves you at the end with a (oftentimes) small confidence in their aggregate normality. Though statisticians have done this in the past. Not encouraged.

Comment: Thank you for the warning. This should also be a case of the multiple testing problem.